# Unable to inject ActionFilter instance using AutoFac

Tags: autofac, asp.net-mvc-5.1

Can someone please tell me where I'm going wrong.  I have an action with the following custom filter attribute...

```
[UserValidation("Standard")]
public ActionResult Index()
```

The custom attribute is defined as...

```
public class UserValidationAttribute : FilterAttribute, IAutofacActionFilter
{
    public ILogger Logger { get; set; }

    private string _status;

    public UserValidationAttribute (string status)
    {
        // At this point in the code, 'Logger' is null
        _status = status;
    }

    public void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
    }
}
```

And I'm building the AutoFac container as...

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

builder.Register(x => new Logger()
                .As<ILogger>()
                .InstancePerHttpRequest();

builder.RegisterFilterProvider();

var container = builder.Build();

System.Web.Mvc.DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
```

and for some reason when the custom action filter's constructor is 'hit', the public 'Logger' property is null?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Turns out there isn't a problem, the public properties are instantiated when a method of the filter is called!